# How to add attributes to product by category in opencart

Tags: php, attributes, e-commerce, opencart, product

I want to Add attributes(Options) to multiple products having same category. Is there an option available in open cart or any way to do this,

If I Add attribute(Options) to products of same category should it apply to all the products?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?

Answer (score 0):

Opencart 2.0

> Put this lines in opencart2\admin\model\catalog\product.php line no 611 approx
>   In     Public function getTotalProducts($data = array()) { ....
>
> Function  And Open
>   opencart2/admin/index.php?route=catalog/product&token=47e2a
>
> Page once and delete this line after executing this lines

```
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT product_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category WHERE category_id = (SELECT category_id FROM `oc_category_description` WHERE name = 'Cameras' AND language_id = '1')");

    foreach ($query->rows as $key) {
      $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_attribute SET product_id = '" . $key['product_id'] . "', attribute_id = '9', language_id = '1', text = 'Testing'");
        }
```

> You Can change Category name -> name = 'Cameras',________
>    Language id -> language_id = '1'(for english), ___________
>   Attribute id ->attribute_id = '9'(You can check attribute id at opencart2/admin/index.php?route=catalog/attribute/edit&token=4e2a&attribute_id=3), ________
>   Attribute Text -> text = 'Testing'

Ask me for more clarity